# CoreData crashes with a small number of users

Tags: swift, core-data, crash

I developed an app focused on health and fitness and to save workout data I use Core Data.
In a small number of users (<0.1%), I get the following error:

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException, Illegal attempt to establish an 'X' relationship between objects in different contexts.

This error occurs when I try to save the training program.
If I log-on with the same user account on my device, this error does not happen.

This is my save function:

```
func saveTraningProgramDB(trainingProgram:RetornoTreino) {
        let db = getContext()
        for ficha in (trainingProgram.programa?.fichas)! {
            let fichasDB = FichasNovoDB(context: db)
            fichasDB.nome = ficha.nome
            ....
            for atividade in ficha.atividades! {
                for atividadePrograma in (trainingProgram.programa?.atividades)! {
                    if atividade.codigoAtividade == String(atividadePrograma.codigoAtividade ?? 0) {
                        let atividadesDB = AtividadesNovoDB(context: db)
                        ...
                        for serie in atividade.series! {
                            let seriesDB = SeriesNovoDB(context: db)
                            ...
                            atividadesDB.addToSeries(seriesDB)
                        }
                        for ajuste in atividade.ajustes! {
                            ...
                            atividadesDB.addToAjustes(ajustesDB)
                        }
                        fichasDB.addToAtividades(atividadesDB)
                    }
                }
            }
            db(fichasDB)
        }
        do {
            try db.save()
        } catch {
            db(error)
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on, or how can I do to simulate the problem as it only happens on the client device ?

Thanks for all replies!

NOTE: Sorry for my English, it is not my native language.

*** SOLVED ***

The problem happened in another part of the code and the error stack featured in this part.
The problem was that the client's cell phone was in 12h and not 24h format.
The date broke because it was not handled correctly.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

It is not visible to see how your contexts are related, but from what I can see there:

You create fichasDB in a context named "db" and add an array actividadesDB as a relationship but the array was created in context "bancoDeDados". That doesnt look right.

Other than that you have to expand your code with more information about the contexts.

Comment: Sorry, when I put the text in the traductor, I forgot to revise the code. The bancoDeDados and db are same context.

Comment: My big problem is that on any device, this method works. But in a specific device generates the exception (NSInvalidArgumentException).